# Nativescript App size after installing 100+ MB

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

When I build a {N} app the ipa or apk file size is 30MB

```
tns build ios --release --for-device
```

and after installing app in device with above build the size is 100MB+ in device.Can any one help me here to how to reduce the app size?

--edited question
After going through webpack,

--- I was upgraded to nativescript(2.5.2) , angular(2.4.5) and core modules(2.5.1) to bundle the app with webpack(2.2.0) and app is running/bundled successfully and the generated ipa(same as for android debug-apk size may be differ) file size is 21.3MB when ran below command is

```
npm run build-ios-bundle --release --for-device
```

But when the app is installed in device/iTunes the size of the app showing 53MB 
[image]

53MB of app size also very huge can any one help me here how to reduce the app size even after webpack integration.
I am sharing my package.json

```
{
  "description": ".....",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": ".....",
  "repository": ".....",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "......",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "2.5.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.5",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.5",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "nativescript-angular": "1.4.1",
    "nativescript-angular-snapshot": "1.3.0-5.2.361",
    "nativescript-cardview": "^1.2.1",
    "nativescript-carousel": "^2.2.0",
    "nativescript-dom": "^1.0.8",
    "nativescript-fresco": "^1.0.16",
    "nativescript-imagepicker": "^2.4.1",
    "nativescript-iqkeyboardmanager": "^1.0.1",
    "nativescript-pdf-view": "latest",
    "nativescript-permissions": "^1.2.2",
    "nativescript-photoviewer": "^1.0.0",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^3.10.2",
    "nativescript-pulltorefresh": "^1.1.10",
    "nativescript-telerik-ui": "^1.5.1",
    "nativescript-theme-core": "^0.2.1",
    "nativescript-toasts": "^1.0.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.1",
    "tns-core-modules": "^2.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~2.4.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.2.10",
    "babel-traverse": "6.8.0",
    "babel-types": "6.8.1",
    "babylon": "6.8.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "~3.0.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~2.0.0-beta.4",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-css-loader": "~0.26.0",
    "nativescript-dev-android-snapshot": "^0.*.*",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.3.6",
    "raw-loader": "~0.5.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "~1.6.0",
    "typescript": "~2.1.0",
    "webpack": "2.2.0",
    "webpack-sources": "~0.1.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.7.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "ns-bundle": "ns-bundle",
    "start-android-bundle": "npm run ns-bundle --android --start-app",
    "start-ios-bundle": "npm run ns-bundle --ios --start-app",
    "build-android-bundle": "npm run ns-bundle --android --build-app",
    "build-ios-bundle": "npm run ns-bundle --ios --build-app"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use webpack to reduce size and performance of your app when making a build - http://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tooling/bundling-with-webpack

Comment: I think what he means is this. Check screenshot [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B70he3QkeE7CamdJZWdQUW8tRHM/view?usp=sharing)

On Android, head to settings > apps > nativescript app > storage

For Material Colors: [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nativescript.materialcolors)

Total: 66.24mb
App: 32.15mb(must be nativescript)
Data: 34.09mb

Our entire app folder is 2.3mb. We do not download or store data. So what data is in the 34mb?

Comment: the data is loaded first time when ur app start up. After that u'll not see any changes in the data size. To test it clear app data from android app settings and relaunch the app and then go back to android app setting and check, the data is same as u'have checked earlier.

Comment: As with my experience my initial app size is 32mb without webpack and total app size is 120mb something with data size upto 70mb.but after webpacking it the size is now around 14mb and total app size including data size is 35mb.

Comment: @Dlucidone can you please check my updated answer .. only 50% of the app size is decreased when used webpack.

Comment: @UpenderDevulapally try removing platform and then making a new build. I 'm sure its the previous builds snapshots thats taking the size